# Some automatically launched Hadoop YARN application

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, hadoop-yarn

I'm new to Apache Hadoop. I've installed a cluster of YARN with one master and two slaves on **AWS**. When I just start the cluster YARN, I could observe that some applications are launched by **user** **dr.who** with **app type YARN** automatically. It bothers me a lot. Hoping someone could help me out of this. Thanks!

```
application_1531399885156_0041  dr.who  hadoop  YARN    default Thu Jul 12 14:58:37 +0200 2018  N/A ACCEPTED    UNDEFINED   ApplicationMaster   0
```

Comment: I can help you with dr.who user. It is the default user in YARN. When no user has submitted the job then it is shown as Dr. Who submitted the job.

Comment: If you look at the YARN UI job logs, what are those jobs doing?

Comment: @Abhinav What do you mean "no user"?

Comment: @cricket_007 well, nothing in the logs. The url is no accessible. And some of them got killed. **Kill application application_1531401785430_0011 received from dr.who (auth:SIMPLE)**

Comment: @Guobao what I mean is when Yarn runs the job by itself only, or when yarn is not able to deduce which user submitted the job then only it shows dr.who as its default user

Comment: Thanks @Abhinav, I think that I got hacked because I opened all the port on this compute on EC2.

Comment: @Guobao That's not the issue. EC2 is safe and secure. You can't be hacked that easily. They warn you about the same but it's not that simple. Moreover, no one will hack you to run their jobs, right? I have given you the reason why it has happened and if you find the answer satisfactory then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in latest launch of Hadoop and a JIRA has also been created. The apps submission by **dr.who** and when the user kills all the jobs then the NodeManager goes down.

**EDIT: Problem Resolution**

**PROBLEM** Customer unable to see logs via Resource Manager UI due to incorrect permissions for the default user dr.who.

**RESOLUTION** Customer changed the following property in core-site.xml to resolve the issue. Other values such as hdfs or mapred also resolve the issue. If the cluster is managed by Ambari, this should be added in Ambari > HDFS > Configurations >Advanced core-site > Add Property

```
hadoop.http.staticuser.user=yarn
```

The same threat was posted on Hortonworks and was answered by Sandeep Nemuri who wrote:

> 1. **Stop further attacks:**
>
> a. Use Firewall / IP table settings to allow access only to whitelisted IP addresses for Resource Manager port (default 8088). Do this on both Resource Managers in your HA setup. This only addresses the current attack. To permanently secure your clusters, all HDP end-points ( e.g WebHDFS) must be blocked from open access outside of firewalls.
>
> b. Make your cluster secure (kerberized).
>
> 2. **Clean up existing attacks:**
>
> a. If you already see the above problem in your clusters, please filter all applications named “MYYARN” and kill them after verifying that these applications are not legitimately submitted by your own users.
>
> b. You will also need to manually login into the cluster machines and check for any process with “z_2.sh” or “/tmp/java” or “/tmp/w.conf” and kill them.

The link to that thread is : [dr.who](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/191898/hdp-261-virus-crytalminer-drwho.html)

Comment: Well thanks for your answer. And do you know how could I find this issue in JIRA?

Comment: I don't have the JIRA link with me but I have the precise solution to this problem. I am editing the question